# Thrift - One way messaging

Tags: python, thrift

Is there a way to implement a "fire-and-forget" asynchronous thrift method call, where the client just sends over information and forgets about it. No waiting for a response, or response callback. Kind of like a message queue, just without the queue. Is there any way to do this with thrift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just add `oneway` to method definition. Of cause, oneway method must return `void`:

```
service MyService {
    //returns immediately
    oneway void onewayMethod(<params>);

    //blocks until completion
    void normalMethod(<params>);
}
```

Comment: exactly. But I'm not sure whether you really want it. It may happen that the server will not receive client call and the client will not know it! I think it's better to return void just to make sure that the request has been processed.